# C++ Fixed-size general-purpose thread pool

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17

I've been reading about thread pools in C++ for a few days now and decided to roll out my own. I mainly intend to use it to learn how to implement parallel algorithms at some point in the future but before that I have to know if there's something I can do to make it more efficient.

These are all the variables I'm using. I decided to put everything inside its own namespace and make the `std::condition_variable` (responsible for pausing the main thread) static because there's really no need for every `thread_pool` object to have a copy of it.

```
namespace async {

    static std::condition_variable main_thread_cv;

    template <size_t Size>
    class thread_pool {

        private:
            std::mutex mutex_m;
            std::atomic<int> busy_m;
            std::condition_variable pool_cv_m;
            std::array<std::thread, Size> workers_m;
            std::queue<std::function<void()>> task_queue_m;
            bool should_terminate_m;
            void thread_loop();

        public:
            thread_pool();
            ~thread_pool();
            thread_pool(const thread_pool& other) = delete;
            thread_pool(const thread_pool&& other) = delete;
            thread_pool& operator=(const thread_pool& other) = delete;
            thread_pool& operator=(const thread_pool&& other) = delete;
            void wait();
            template <typename Fn, typename... Args> void enqueue(Fn&& function, Args&&... args);

    };
...
}
```

This is the thread loop executed by all of the worker threads.

```
template<size_t Size>
void thread_pool<Size>::thread_loop() {

    thread_local std::function<void()> task;

    for (;;) {
        { std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_m);
            pool_cv_m.wait(lock, [this]() { return !task_queue_m.empty() || should_terminate_m; });
            if (should_terminate_m) {
                break;
            }
            task = task_queue_m.front();
            task_queue_m.pop();
        }
        busy_m++;
        task();
        busy_m--;
        main_thread_cv.notify_one();
    }

}
```

ctor and dtor:

```
template<size_t Size>
thread_pool<Size>::thread_pool() {

    busy_m = 0;
    should_terminate_m = false;

    for (auto& thread : workers_m) {
        thread = std::thread([this]() { thread_loop(); });
    }

}

template<size_t Size>
thread_pool<Size>::~thread_pool() {

    busy_m = 0;
    should_terminate_m = true;

    pool_cv_m.notify_all();

    for (auto& thread : workers_m) {
        thread.join();
    }

}
```

The `wait` and `enqueue` functions:

```
template<size_t Size>
void thread_pool<Size>::wait() {

    { std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_m);
        main_thread_cv.wait(lock, [this]() { return busy_m == 0 && task_queue_m.empty(); });
    }

}

template<size_t Size>
template<typename Fn, typename ...Args>
void thread_pool<Size>::enqueue(Fn&& function, Args&& ...args) {

    { std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_m);
        task_queue_m.push(std::bind(std::forward<Fn>(function), std::forward<Args>(args)...));
        pool_cv_m.notify_one();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ensure the mutex is locked when changing `should_terminate_m`

In the destructor, you should hold the mutex locked while changing `should_terminate_m`. It may work as it is in this particular case, but in general, if you hold a mutex while accessing a variable anywhere in the code (it's held in `thread_loop()` while reading it), you should hold the mutex everywhere you access it. This avoids unexpected behavior.

## Stick with either `std::unique_lock` or `std::scoped_lock`

You use both types of locks in the code. While functionally it should be perfectly fine, it's weird to mix these two. Be consistent and use only one of them. I recommend sticking with `std::scoped_lock` if you don't mind not being compatible with pre-C++17 compilers.

## Issues with `wait()`

One issue I see is that in order to support the `wait()` member function, you have a reference counter `busy_m`, and you have to notify the condition vairable `pool_cv_m` every time a task finishes. This adds overhead even if nothing is actually calling `wait()`, but more importantly, because you use `main_thread_cv.notify_one()`, if multiple threads are calling `wait()`, then the notification might go to the wrong thread.

Another issue is that if jobs are enqueued often enough that the queue is never empty, `wait()` never returns, even though all jobs that were enqueued before `wait()` was called did finish.

You could indeed make it explicit that only the main thread is allowed to enqueue jobs and call `wait()`, but that might limit the usefulness of this thread pool somewhat.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I decided to just make the `should_terminate_m` atomic to not worry about locking it and replace the `std::scoped_lock` with `std::unique_lock` because the condition_variable wouldn't let me use the former. I do not understand how `wait()` never returning is a problem in this scenario though. The tasks must be queued up before calling the `wait()` function so it not ever returning unless the queue gets empty and nothing is being done by the threads would mean it works as expected.

Comment: Making `should_terminate_m` atomic does not help here. You must ensure access to `should_terminate_m` is done while `mutex_m` is held to ensure proper synchronization with `pool_cv_m`.

Comment: Ah, right. Didn't think about it, ty